# Spacing on a table border-bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I am using the css to show a bottom border.

```
.inset {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadce0;
}
```

I'd like for there to be some space on the left and right sides much like using a `<hr align="center" width="80%">` but I simply am not finding this is possible.

Are there any properties I should look at or CSS tricks I should investigate to leave the table intact and be able to see a bottom border that is centered but taking up only 80% of the table width?

Comment: `I'd like for there to be some space on the left and right sides` i have no idea what this means, can you make a sketch or a preview of how you want it to look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your table to a width of 80% (leaving 10% for the left and right margins), and then center the whole table:

```css
.inset {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadce0;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: coral;
}

.inset td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="inset">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 - Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 - Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 - Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 - Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 - Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 - Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3 - Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your bottom border is outside of your `<table>` tags you could wrap it in a div, display it as flex, justify it center, and then give it a width of 80%. I think that will do what you are wanting. If that doesn't work have you tried just using the margin properties?

`margin-left: 10%;` for example.

Its hard to give you much more direction without seeing some more of your html/css and how you have implemented your border.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution? It's CSS only.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

table:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 10%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>Carrot</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```